# Python Webdriver - How do I handle or bypass the 'local storage' dialog?

Tags: python, webdriver, local-storage, selenium-chromedriver, alert

[image]

How do I click 'Allow' on this local storage chromedriver browser dialog? or completely bypass / disable it?

I have tried the following methods:

**[TRIED METHOD 1: - Disable Chrome Notifications]**

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**[TRIED METHOD 2: - Disable Chrome Extensions]**

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**[TRIED METHOD 3: - Disable Chrome Notifications (Another Way)]**

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**[TRIED METHOD 4: - Accept the Dialog]**

```
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

**[Possible Solutions?]**

- Maybe I could use python to somehow call a javascript that disables localstorage after the chromedriver instance is running?

You probably already gathered I am very green. As a result..
Your knowledge and wisdom would be greatly appreciated! =)

*My current lame working Hack is an X,Y Coordinate Mouse Click.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I GOT IT WORKING!!! =) =) =)***

**--unlimited-storage is the key!!!!!!**

**[SOLUTION 1]**

*Note: This is the best solution, it completely bypasses the Alert!*

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--unlimited-storage")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

**[SOLUTION 2]**

AutoHotKey - I call the following 'TabEnter.ahk' script within Python.

*NOTE: When the Alert or whatever it is called is up, a TAB then ENTER keypress will also handle it. The problem with this method is if you click somewhere else while automation is running, AutoHotkey will lose focus on the button. So it is best to only be used on a system that has no user intervention.*

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
SendMode Input
SendInput {tab}
SendInput {enter}
```

If anybody would like more info on how I implemented this, please let me know =)